# How to find the closed form of a multiple integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to find the closed form of the following $$\int\limits_{t<t_p<\cdots<t_1<1} t_1^{n_1-1}\cdots t_p^{n_p-1}dt_1\cdots dt_p,$$
where $p,n_j\ (j=1,2,\ldots,p)$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(\{n_1,\cdots,n_p\},t)$ denote the integral. Then we have the following recursive formula:

$$ F(\{n_1,\cdots,n_p\},t) = \int_{t}^{1} \tau^{n_p-1} F(\{n_1,\cdots,n_{p-1}\}, \tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau, \qquad F(\varnothing, t) = 1. $$

If we write $s_k = n_1 + \cdots + n_k$ and $s_0 = 0$, then

> $$ F(\{n_1, \cdots, n_p\}, t) = \sum_{k=0}^{p} \frac{t^{s_p - s_k}}{\prod_{j\neq k} (s_k - s_j)}. \tag{*} $$

Indeed, $\text{(*)}$ is trivial if $p = 0$, and assuming $\text{(*)}$ for $p$,

\begin{align*}
F(\{n_1,\cdots,n_{p+1}\},t)
&= \int_{t}^{1} \tau^{n_{p+1}-1} F(\{n_1,\cdots,n_p\}, \tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau \\
&= \int_{t}^{1} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{p} \frac{\tau^{s_{p+1} - s_k - 1}}{\prod_{j\neq k} (s_k - s_j)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\tau \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{p} \frac{1 - t^{s_{p+1} - s_k}}{(s_{p+1} - s_k) \prod_{j\neq k} (s_k - s_j)} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{p} \frac{1}{(s_{p+1} - s_k) \prod_{j\neq k} (s_k - s_j)} + \left( \sum_{k=0}^{p} \frac{t^{s_{p+1} - s_k}}{\prod_{j\neq k} (s_k - s_j)} \right)
\end{align*}

The sum in the constant term can be shown to be $1/\prod_{j=1}^{p} (s_{p+1} - s_j)$, and so, $\text{(*)}$ holds for $p+1$. Now the desired claim follows the induction on $p$.